# How do I use Random properly to generate number for text-based combat simulator game?

Tags: c#, random

I'm trying to use Random to generate random number for a text-based combat simulator but it keeps generating a very large and unusual number.

Here is the code:

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Starting Simulator");
        Actor FoxTail = new Actor();
        FoxTail.HealthPoints = 15;
        FoxTail.Strength = 2;
        FoxTail.Defense = 12;
        FoxTail.Spirit = 12;
        FoxTail.Dexterity = 2;
        FoxTail.Agility = 3;
        FoxTail.Intelligence = 2;
        FoxTail.Level = 0;
        FoxTail.ExperiencePoints = 0;
        Actor GreyWolf = new Actor();
        GreyWolf.HealthPoints = 25;
        GreyWolf.Strength = 2;
        GreyWolf.Defense = 10;
        GreyWolf.Spirit = 8;
        GreyWolf.Dexterity = 5;
        GreyWolf.Agility = 7;
        GreyWolf.Intelligence = 2;
        GreyWolf.Level = 1;
        GreyWolf.ExperiencePoints = 5;
        int FoxTailAttack = new Randomizer.RandomIntegerGenerator(1).GeneratePositiveValue();
        if(FoxTailAttack >= GreyWolf.Defense)
        {
            int damage = new Randomizer.RandomIntegerGenerator(1).GeneratePositiveValue() + FoxTail.Strength;
            GreyWolf.HealthPoints = GreyWolf.HealthPoints - damage;
            Console.WriteLine("Grey Wolf is at " + GreyWolf.HealthPoints + " health!");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Foxtail missed!");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm assuming the '1' in the parathesis after `RandomIntegerGenerator` is where my problem lies, but I just don't know how to define a range for the random number to generate. I get a weird -534011695 number that gets outputted in my runtime window. I'd like to get it to generate a number beween 1 and 25 if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using some `Randomizer` class from somewhere else. You don't need that. C# comes with the `Random` class, that has everything you need.

Only create one instance of the `Random` class and use it throughout the whole application. This is important because the instance is initialized with the current time as a random seed value when the instance is created. If you created a new instance each time, you would often get sequences of the same random number.

```
internal class Program
{
    public static Random Randomizer { get; private set; } = new Random();
```

You can then use the Next method to retrieve a random integer number in a given range:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for(int i=0; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        // Create integers >= 1 and < 26. 
        // The result can be 1 and 25, but not 26
        int number = Randomizer.Next(1, 26);

        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());
    }
}
```

The call `Randomizer.Next(1, 26);` will return values from 1 to 25.